# Automatically generating update and Insert scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am importing data from a third party database. Following various actions carried out on the data by my software application, I then need to automatically produce update and insert scripts to amend / append to the original 3rd party database. There will be in the region of 20 scripts to amend 20 tables.

The live 3rd party database is held remotely of my server which holds a backup of the data only. The data to be amended will be static on the live database during the exercise I am performing.

Does anyone know of an application that will assist in preparing these scripts?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just save a backup and restore it when needed?

Comment: Other elements of the 3rd party database will be in use by others during the time frame concerned so a full restore is not possible

Comment: you can use replication,if you want to keep both databases upto date(if this is the intent)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services was designed for ETL jobs and can help with complicated workflows (lots of dependancies and ordering etc.);

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services

However I personally prefer to simply write SQL scripts and schedule them using SQL Server Agent. If you do wish to use a graphical tool though - SSIS is probably your best bet.

If you want to get clever and dynamically generate these (if the procedure for the 20 tables is standard) you can use BIML to ninja up one package which will work for all tables: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3094/introduction-to-business-intelligence-markup-language-biml-for-ssis/

Comment: I'm not sure if the above will work for my situation as the 3rd party database may be remote of my updated database, therefore I envisaged needing to produce the insert or update script and issue it to the 3rd party for them to run on their database. I'll update the question now as this was not clear sorry.